# Django is giving me a 404 error

Tags: django, debian, django-settings

I installed Django, and it works. I set it up so it uses my mysql database, and I started a project. So far so good.

I followed the tutorial on setting up your first Django app over at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

It is a tutorial over setting up a pre-existing poll app where everything has practically been built for you. The database structure has even been handled.

I ran:

`python manage.py startapp polls`

`python manage.py sql polls`

`python manage.py syncdb`

I didn't receive any kind of success message so I went into my phpmyadmin, and hooray! There are new tables and rows in my database.

Their tutorial then told me to run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and that I'd see some database stuff, but I didn't. Why could this be? I ignored it and went on to step two. I still hadn't set DEBUG in my `settings.py` to False so I did. Only to get a 500 error.

After some digging I read I needed to add:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my ip address'];
```

I did this and now after running:

```
python manage.py runserver myip:8000
```

When I try to access Django in my browser I get a

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Obviously / changes to a different location when navigating to those places as well, but the point is I get a 404 no matter what.

So I look at my terminal and I have a yellow message in my terminal that says.

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 74

and there is 1 message like this for each place I tried to access.

I'm thinking there is a Python package that I don't have installed on my server?

I do not want to use ALLOWED_HOSTS ['*'] I read that this is bad practice. I did try it and it produces the same results as using my ip address in place of the * (I just wanted to add that extra piece of info in case it helps)

Comment: Does your view raise a 404 error?  Are there no error messages at all?

Comment: My view in the browser says, 
"Not Found (new line) The requested URL / was not found on this server." Which is what most 404s look like.
In my terminal it actually says 404 (read above)

Comment: It could be I have  a wrong path to the WSGI script . Where would the log to check this be?

Comment: debug it with firebug... I think, url is not getting found...

Comment: Which url are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the database shell, you should run the `dbshell` command instead of `shell` as in your post, like this:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

If you run `shell`, you get a Python shell, where you can easily import and inspect the Python objects of your project.

On your local PC, it's better to have `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py`. That way you don't need to bother about `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, because in debug mode all hosts are allowed. Secondly, when you get a 404 error in debug mode, the page will show you the valid URLs that you can try.

The Django tutorial certainly works. The only way it won't work *for you* is if you missed a step or mistyped something somewhere. If you start over and pay extra attention, I think it will work.

Comment: Installed it twice. Same problem each time. I followed everything exactly. Are you positive the tutorial didn't just assume everyone knew something and left it out? We can go on all day saying things like that. Thing is I've seen this issue all over the net but I can't seem to find an answer. So instead of giving a generic broad answer maybe help troubleshoot.  Thanks anyway. I know that for a fact the tutorial doesn't mention adding the allowed_hosts or including your projects conf. Those are two pretty big pieces of info. So isn't there a chance something else might have been left out to?

Comment: All I get no matter where I am with Debug set to true is **Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Here's what to do next:
If you plan to use a database, edit the DATABASES setting in firstweb/settings.py.
Start your first app by running python manage.py startapp [appname].
You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!**

Comment: I've all read started my project and added my database stuff which works. I mentioned all of that in my OP. I figure i should have set a url somewhere and I'll look into that.

Comment: (Deleted..) i followed the tutorial on installing Django word for word. They could do things I couldn't. I followed the app tutorial word for word, and they could do things I couldn't. There has to be some kind of extra step here and there. I mean I followed it word for word, step by step.. I guess I'll try a third install after reading a bit more.

Comment: I went into my urls.py and uncommented my urls. I didn't realize they were commented. Now I'm getting something different. Now I'm not getting the default view, but instead a page where I'm told I have an import error and that **No module named foo.urls** Was that something I was supposed to add at some point? I'd rather see if I'm close before I reinstall. bet I didn't uncomment something in setting.py under installed apps.

Comment: Leave the commented lines in `urls.py` as they are. They are just examples. Later on in the tuto you have to add lines that correspond to your app (instead of `foo` in the examples)

Comment: At which exact step in the tuto do you see things different from the way it's written? Once I know that it should be straightforward to debug. I have to have lunch now. But it really looks like you're not following the tutorial well, either because you accidentally skipped steps or because you did something that was not written and you shouldn't have. Many people completed this you know (including myself), it really works.

Comment: Yes. I added it after I started my project. I'm just going to reinstall again. There are several basic things left out of the tutorial that i didn't know about. Thank you.

Comment: If you tell me item by item what the tuto left out, I can double check. As for `shell`, I think nothing's left out, it's well explained on the first page that it's a Python shell, to explore the API, not about database shell. Anything else unclear? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/